# help me improve my basic point to point move animation algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation

Greetings,
With javascript, I am trying to make a very easy animation, an image moves from one X and Y coordination to another X Y coordination.
I have 4 constant such as:

```
var startX = 0; //starting X of an image
var startY = 0; //starting Y of an image
var endX = 100; //ending X of an image
var endY = 200; //ending Y of an image

//these 2 are used for keeping the "current" position of animated image, 
var currentX = startX ;
var currentY = startY ;

//every 150 ms, updates the location of the coordinates
function move(){

if( (currentX == endX) && (currentY == endY) )
break;

if(currentX  < endX){
currentX  = currentX  + step_amount;
}

if(currentX  > endX){
currentX  = currentX  - step_amount;
}

if(currentY < endY){
currentY = currentY + step_amount;
}

if(currentY > endY){
currentY = currentY - step_amount;
}
setInterval("move()", 150);
}
```

This does the job, however it is not smooth, I will be grateful if you help me improve my naive algorithm for a better move function that is always going for the "shortest path".

Comment: How do you set/calulate step_amount, and shouldn't you have different step values for x and y dimensions if you want to move in a straight line?

Comment: Change the last line to setInterval(move, 50).  It will be three times smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need (a variation of) the [Bresenham line drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest distance between two points is a straight line. So you should probably move along that.

What that would imply is that in your code, you should not use the same step amount for both X and Y coordinates. Instead compute Y step based on X step and the slope of the shortest path line.

```
slope = (startY - endY) / (startX - endX);
Y_step = X_step * slope;
```

Secondly, in your current algorithm, once your image reaches the destination point, it'll continue to oscillate about it. I think you should get rid of the statements that take a negative step.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always moving two coordinates together, you only need to check against one of them, e.g.

```
if (currentX < endX) {
    currentX += xStep;
    currentY += yStep;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to move the object in a straight line:

```
var numberOfSteps = 100;
var stepDX = (endX - startX) / numberOfSteps;
var stepDY = (endY - startY) / numberOfSteps;
var step = 0;
```

Inside the move() function:

```
if (step <= numberOfSteps) {
    currentX = startX + stepDX * step;
    currentY = startY + stepDY * step;
    step++;
}
```

Cast currentX/currentY to integer before applying to the object you want to move.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation, many thanks to Frederik The Fool

Compute slope:

```
if(this.x === target.x){
    this.slope = 1;
}else{
    this.slope = (this.y - target.y)/(this.x - target.x);
}
```

Ystep:

```
if(this.y > this.target.y){ 
    this.y = Math.max(this.target.y, this.y - Math.abs(this.slope * distance));
}else if(this.shape.y < this.target.y){
    this.y = Math.min(this.target.y, this.y + Math.abs(this.slope * distance));
}
```