# Can this animation in jquery be done in JS without jquery and still retain simplicity?

Tags: javascript, animation, mouse

I found this "div follows mouse" animation: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88526/1/) that belongs to the answer posted in: [How to animate following the mouse in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847726/how-to-animate-following-the-mouse-in-jquery).

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

​

I got quite intrigued by the inner workings and I tried to understand what the code is doing. I am currently learning javascript and I tried to replicate the "point to point" animation. I found this: [Point to point animation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057359/help-me-improve-my-basic-point-to-point-move-animation-algorithm), but it feels that the code of the original poster is pretty long and repetitive.

My current basic level of javascript is being an obstacle to fully understand the jQuery version (i still didn't enter into the jQuery realm). Yet, I think that do this kind of animation in javascript might be possible, but the only way I can think about is with a code similar to the "point to point" link.

Can something like this be done with a code as short as the jQuery version? Or to do just javascript requires much longer routine?

Thanks for any suggestion or comment that you might have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can something like this be done with a code as short as the jQuery version?

In this case, nearly, yes, because what's being done is fairly simple and only a small amount of jQuery's functionality is used. Specifically:

- It's hooking the `mousemove` event on `document`, which can easily be done with [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-EventTarget-addEventListener) (or `attachEvent` on older versions of IE).
- It's locating an element by `id` (`$("#follower")`), which can easily be done with [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId).
- It's setting the `left` and `top` of an element via jQuery's `css` function. This can easily be done by setting the `left` and `top` properties on the element's [`style` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#dom-style).

Putting that all together: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88526/1480/)

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler, false);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
}
else {
    document.onmousemove = function(event) {
        mouseMoveHandler(event || window.event);
    };
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
}

// cache the element
var follower = document.getElementById("follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
follower.style.left = xp + "px";
follower.style.top  = yp + "px";

}, 30);
```

As you can see, the biggest issue is hooking the event in a way that plays nicely with others. Although you *could* just use the `document.onmousemove` version, that would clobber any other `mousemove` handlers on `document`, which is why we first look for `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`.

Some handy references, in roughly chronological order (latter ones update/supercede/add to earlier ones):

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)
- [Other DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

None of which should be taken to say that you can't use a good library like jQuery, there are several good reasons to (the events thing above is just one example). But it's always best to understand the basics as well, even if you use a library to avoid having to deal with them all that much.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to keep reading the references. I quite like this language, and your explanation is very complete, so I hope my skills keep growing!

Comment: Also note you could simply write `Node.prototype.addEventListener = Node.prototype.addEventListener || Node.prototype.attachEvent` once and simply use `addEventListener` from then on.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Can you? I thought the versions of IE that don't have `addEventListener` *also* don't support extending the prototypes of HTML elements. (Well, I don't know for sure about IE8, but IE6 and IE7 don't allow element prototype extensions.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Didn't know about that, sorry. I certainly did succeed extending `Array` in IE8.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yeah, IE (at least back through IE6, probably even earlier) is happy to allow you to extend *JavaScript*'s objects' prototypes. But not the host-provided things (in this case, HTML elements).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IIRC the ECMAScript standard allows you to extend _any_ object. This doesn't say much about what IE allows, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not host objects, they're special. Amongst other things, they're [not required to have prototypes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2). Host objects are also not required to allow you to extend them (add properties ad hoc).